# Fragment won't switch after the OS kills my app

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity with a **BottomNavigationView** that switches between 3 fragments. My three fragments are automatically restored when the activity is recreated. Therefore, I guard my fragments' creation in the activity's `OnCreate` with a `savedInstanceState == null` check to ensure that I don't add additional fragments on top of the ones already created/restored.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    // Fragments are automatically restored when activity is recreated
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_main, mTrendingFragment, "3").hide(mTrendingFragment).commit();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_main, mFavoriteFragment, "2").hide(mFavoriteFragment).commit();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_main, mUpcomingViewPagerFragment, "1").commit();
}
```

Now, the problem is when I come back to my activity from the background after some time and try to switch to another fragment, it doesn't work. The home fragment is always the one showing even when I click on the other's fragment menu item in the **BottomNavigationView**; it doesn't switch the fragment. Why is this happening and how can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're still unconditionally creating brand new instances in your onCreate() when you do:

```
// Default fragment
mUpcomingViewPagerFragment = new UpcomingViewPagerFragment();
mFavoriteFragment = new FavoriteFragment();
mTrendingFragment = new TrendingFragment();
```

When you restore your instance (and `savedInstanceState` is **not** equal to `null`), you never add those brand new fragments to the FragmentManager, so calling `hide()`, `show()`, etc with those Fragments does nothing.

Instead, you need to retrieve those Fragments from the FragmentManager so that your instance variables match the Fragments that the FragmentManager knows about:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    // Create brand new Fragments
    mUpcomingViewPagerFragment = new UpcomingViewPagerFragment();
    mFavoriteFragment = new FavoriteFragment();
    mTrendingFragment = new TrendingFragment();

    // Add the brand new Fragments to the FragmentManager
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_main, mTrendingFragment, "3").hide(mTrendingFragment).commit();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_main, mFavoriteFragment, "2").hide(mFavoriteFragment).commit();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_main, mUpcomingViewPagerFragment, "1").commit();
} else {
    // Retrieve the already existing Fragments from the FragmentManager
    mUpcomingViewPagerFragment = (UpcomingViewPagerFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("1");
    mFavoriteFragment = (FavoriteFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("2");
    mTrendingFragment = (TrendingFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("3");
}
```

Comment: You're the best